# Merge JSON's fields (date and time) and store as Date object

Tags: java, gson, retrofit

I use retrofit. JSON keeps date and time in separate fields. I wanna merge date and time and save as Date object. Is it possible using retrofit and GSON?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by implementing my own JsonDeserializer

Comment: Yep, sometimes actually writing code is the way to solve a programming problem.